# Using mixins for private fields or abstract methods Dart

Tags: dart

I am experimenting with Dart mixins and noticed that

1. You can use private fields in mixins
2. Even abstract methods like abstract classes.

Imagine you have few abstract methods no need to create an abstract ad extend it, you can collect them inside  a mixin and re-use it.
The discussion goes whether you like to have inheritance within your design

Here is a code snippet:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

mixin Favourite {
  bool _isFavourite = false;
  bool get isFavourite;
}

class ProductProvider
    with Favourite, ChangeNotifier
    implements Comparable<ProductProvider> {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String description;
  final String imageUrl;
  final double price;

  ProductProvider({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.description,
    required this.imageUrl,
    required this.price,
  });

  ProductProvider.noPrice({
    required this.id,
    required this.title,
    required this.description,
    required this.imageUrl,
    bool isFavourite = false,
  }) : price = 0.0;

  toggleFavourite() {
    this._isFavourite = !this._isFavourite;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  @override
  bool get isFavourite => _isFavourite;

  factory ProductProvider.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return json['price'] != null
        ? ProductProvider(
            id: json['id'],
            title: json['title'],
            description: json['description'],
            imageUrl: json['imageUrl'],
            price:
                json['price'] is int ? json['price'].toDouble() : json['price'])
        : ProductProvider.noPrice(
            id: json['id'],
            title: json['title'],
            description: json['description'],
            imageUrl: json['imageUrl'],
            isFavourite: json['isFavourite'] ?? false,
          );
  }

  @override
  int compareTo(ProductProvider other) {
    return (price - other.price).toInt();
  }

}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The question is:
Is it ok to mixins for abstract methods or private fields?

Comment: Both work, both have uses, so yes. Why are you worried that it wouldn't be OK?

Comment: Coming from OO languages, mixin is new to me i guess thats why i am not really sure if its good to use it .
You are right dart gives that possibility i should not be worried:)